# Different subversion clients in the same repository

Tags: windows, macos, svn

Can I have two users (1 OSX/MacOS & 1 Windows) using different Subversion clients working on the same repository?

Comment: You can certainly have more than one user working in a single repository.  It won't restrict clients they use.  Just need to be careful re: end of line chars.  Mac, Unix, and Windows are all different.

Comment: Do you actually men "repository" (your project on the server) or do you really mean "working copy" (the files and folders you work with on your computer)? The answer is different for each.

Answer (score 0):

All Subversion 1.x clients are compatible with all Subversion 1.x servers via the RA layer (so no `file:///` access allowed!), and there is no (technical) limit to the number of users you can have for a repository.

When operating on a given working copy, all clients must be the same minor version (1.7.x, 1.8.x, for example).

You should not use multiple people or multiple operating systems with a single working copy.